# How to fetch the image that was uploaded from an android app in wordpress using json api webservice

Tags: php, android, json, wordpress, web-services

We are developing an application with android as frontend and backend with wordpress. My scenario is i was uploading an image from android app and i have to fetch the image, image name in wordpress using json api plugin which was written as a json webservice in wordpress.

I am unable to fetch the image using the POST method that was sent from the android app. The image is getting converted into a byte array in android and how to fetch that image in wordpress json service.

Can anyone provide me with some example code.